# Google API malfunctioning - ImportError: cannot import name 'build'

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

At first, I hoped I could find this problem anywhere on the internet, but I've searched a while and couldn't find anyone with a similar problem. When I try to run the `googleapiclient` module, it kinda fails somewhere - and I'm not sure what's going wrong.
To test it, I've started to run the following file:

```py
import googleapiclient
print('Step one!')
import googleapiclient.discovery
print('Step two!')
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
print('Yay! All steps complete!')
```

The first import goes well, as the first print statement is made successfully. However, after that, it all seems to go wrong;

```
Step one!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Bram/Documents/My Project/src/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import googleapiclient.discovery
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 32, in <module>
    from six.moves import http_client
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Users\Bram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "c:\Users\Bram\Documents\My Project\src\calendar.py", line 5, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: cannot import name 'build'
```

I've tried to force reinstall the module using `pip`. I've installed any package that people suggested on similar threads where people had trouble with this package, *(talking about `apiclient`, `httplib2`, `oauth2client` and `uritemplate`)* and I'm really confused about this Traceback as it seems to refer to two different lines in my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have caused a circular import. Your file is called `calendar.py`, which hides the standard library module of the same name. As you can see in the traceback, `_parseaddr.py` imports `calendar`, expecting to find the stdlib module, but finds yours instead, and is now in a circle.

Rename your file to something else.

Comment: I got a diferent error now _(http_client doesn't have the attribute UNAUTHORIZED)_ - but this one's solved! Got really stuck on this one. Thanks!

Comment: If you get a 'ImportError: bad magic number' when you rerun your script, you'll also need to delete the .pyc file associated with the script (in this case, `rm calendar.pyc`). This shouldn't cause any harm since the pyc file will just get regenerated automatically when you re-run the new .py file.